# How to process Unstuctured data thru Mapreduce

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to understand Unstructured data first. To me mentioned below is the Unstructured data. I have followed thru the "Hadoop : Definitive Guide" mentioning Earthquake example and that is a structred data have positions defined for location, scale, and Geo.

Can anyone help me if one gets a unstructered data as below to have Mapreduce program to get to know at which Geo, How many people are talking about Apple, iPhone and Samasung for eg.?

```
Liyyah_xoxoIG: Liyyah_xoxoeating an apple it's good lol ?
elisaeiyoktaviaItu samsung apa yah ?? :s ngiler dah  x_x
congduc3I just moved up to level 4 in #CSRRacing for iPhone! You should check it out for FREE! http://t.co/dyEXQmQbgS@. Í
MDAUD97Hollywood, CaliforniaRT @CNET: Here's how to hack apps into multi-window mode on the Samsung Galaxy Note 2: http://t.co/p2ZsITDhB3
lasirenerRiad???? ????? ???? ?????? ?? ?????? ?? ???? ????? ??? ?????? ???? ...??? ??? ????? ???? ????? ?????? ????? ???????...
http://t.co/PArHmN4mvK
bimandaldoSir Matt Busby WayWonge wae cino mbak, tp cino ireng RT @ardikawp: Kendel men"@bimandaldo: Iphone cino mbak RT @ajengpradiptasr: Iphone kan bisa ngirim foto l
Hatemmuhamed1RT @M_7assib: ??????? ?????? ??? ???? ?? ???? ?? iPhone.
deepakabhishek2indiaSamsung Galaxy S4 already hits 6 million sales http://t.co/KZ3KEUgtYT
tanhuifang1989I've collected 42,140 gold coins! http://t.co/MpmNDY6ebA #iphone, #iphonegames, #gameinsight
ThomasNachlikMünster, Germanyjust finished a Runtastic bike trip of 19.85 km in 43m 58s with #Runtastic PRO iPhone app: http://t.co/L3EK9lznBL
figbishI've collected 46,475 gold coins! http://t.co/pd6wQwsZrF #iphone, #iphonegames, #gameinsight
gutjahrThe WebKo(s)mische Zufälle: #Apple App-Store-Zähler erreicht die 50 Milliarden exakt zur Eröffnungskeynote der großen #Google I/O Konferenz.
a_sifon_421??????
?????????????????????iPhone???????????????????????????????????????
```

Thanks for quick responses.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0):

It would be an usual mapper program where we can get access to above text. You can use any Java String API or Regular expressions and parse text in you own way and can extract information like Geo, Handset type etc. Then you can write them into context which at later point becomes input to the reducer. It would be quite a regular summarizer on counts that you need.

You can look at below link for some sample on how regular expressions can be used in java
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the first thing which you should consider is the InputFormat which you need in order to process this kind of data. By looking at the data it seems to me that it is a flat binary file(please let me know if I am wrong, i'll update the answer accordingly)

Now, considering it to be binary file, the first hurdle would be be to write a custom InputFormat as Hadoop doesn't provide any InputFormat OOTB that can handle flat binary files. You could not use the available InputFormats as their won't be any delimiter to create the splits(like \n in case of TextInputFormat). Your InputFormat could be something like this :

Read a specified no. of bytes as a byte[], starting from byte 0 and convert this byte[] array into a string which will be fed to the mappers as a Text value(the InputSplit) along with some key, say the line no. The no. of bytes which you are going to use for generating the InputSplit should be configurable and could be set through the Job during job setup.

After this it should be your logic to extract the fields of your interest and throw them to the reducer.

```
YourInputFormat<Length, byte[], LongWritable, Text> -> Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> -> Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
```

HTH

P.S. : It is just a blueprint.